# Create an array of subscribers in ROS 2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. Sorry for all mistakes. English is not my native tongue. In ROS 1, I have code that looks something like this:

```
std::vector<ros::Subscriber> sub_sensors_front;

void EnableSensors(bool enable)
{
  if (enable)
  {
    sub_sensors_front = {
      pNodeHandle->subscribe("/minicar/sensor/front_0", 10, SensorInput),
      pNodeHandle->subscribe("/minicar/sensor/front_1", 10, SensorInput),
      pNodeHandle->subscribe("/minicar/sensor/front_2", 10, SensorInput),
      pNodeHandle->subscribe("/minicar/sensor/front_3", 10, SensorInput),
      pNodeHandle->subscribe("/minicar/sensor/front_4", 10, SensorInput),
    };
  }
}
```

It is working fine. Now I need to migrate my code to ROS 2 foxy, and I am stuck. All I could achieve looks like this, and it is not working.

```
std::vector<rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msg::msg::Range>> sub_sensors_front;

void EnableSensors(bool enable)
{
  if (enable)
  {
    sub_sensors_front = {
      pNodeHandle->create_subscription<sensor_msg::msg::Range>("/minicar/sensor/front_0", 10, SensorInput),
      pNodeHandle->create_subscription<sensor_msg::msg::Range>("/minicar/sensor/front_1", 10, SensorInput),
      pNodeHandle->create_subscription<sensor_msg::msg::Range>("/minicar/sensor/front_2", 10, SensorInput),
      pNodeHandle->create_subscription<sensor_msg::msg::Range>("/minicar/sensor/front_3", 10, SensorInput),
      pNodeHandle->create_subscription<sensor_msg::msg::Range>("/minicar/sensor/front_4", 10, SensorInput),
    };
  }
}
```

VS code following error:

```
no operator '=' matches these operands
```

I would appreciate all possible help. If there is a working example, I would be very grateful for it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407530/create-an-array-of-subscribers-in-ros-2/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are following two issues which you should pay attention to:

1. The callback needs to be attached using `std::bind` function
2. The returned value from `create_subscription` is a shared pointer

An example is shown below:

```
rclcpp::Subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));
```

Below is the complete code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
using std::placeholders::_1;
using MyDataType = std_msgs::msg::String;

class MinimalSubscriber : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  MinimalSubscriber() : Node("minimal_subscriber")
  {
    auto fn = std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1);
    sub_string_front_ = {
      this->create_subscription<MyDataType>("topic_0", 10, fn),
      this->create_subscription<MyDataType>("topic_1", 10, fn),
      this->create_subscription<MyDataType>("topic_2", 10, fn),
      this->create_subscription<MyDataType>("topic_3", 10, fn),
      this->create_subscription<MyDataType>("topic_4", 10, fn),
    };
  }

private:
  void topic_callback(const MyDataType::SharedPtr msg) const
  {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%s'", msg->data.c_str());
  }

  std::vector<rclcpp::Subscription<MyDataType>::SharedPtr> sub_string_front_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<MinimalSubscriber>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

I published string data, and the above code could pick it up, as shown below:

```
$ ros2 topic pub /topic_0 std_msgs/String "data: this is topic 0"
$ ros2 topic pub /topic_1 std_msgs/String "data: this is topic 1"
$ ros2 topic pub /topic_2 std_msgs/String "data: this is topic 2"
$ ros2 topic pub /topic_3 std_msgs/String "data: this is topic 3"
$ ros2 topic pub /topic_4 std_msgs/String "data: this is topic 4"
$ ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber subscriber_member_function
[INFO] [1665135719.026351648] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: 'this is topic 3'
[INFO] [1665135719.111050972] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: 'this is topic 0'
[INFO] [1665135719.111050972] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: 'this is topic 1'
[INFO] [1665135719.480602787] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: 'this is topic 2'
[INFO] [1665135719.495162462] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: 'this is topic 4'
[INFO] [1665135720.026269129] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: 'this is topic 3'
[INFO] [1665135720.111080977] [minimal_subscriber]: I heard: 'this is topic 0'
```

As always, [ros2/examples](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/foxy) and [ros2/demos](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/foxy) are your good friend. So feel free to look at them.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-07**:
Thank you for quick and detailed answer! I'l try this

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-07**:
I saw the "closed" tag with the following message: *Closed for the following reason the question is answered, right answer was accepted by Edvard. close date 2022-10-07 07:00:52.174342*

@Edvard: The correct way to accept an answer is mentioned below:

1. First, upvote the answer. Please click on the ^ icon at the top left side of this answer to do this.
2. Next, please click on the check mark symbol, ✔ icon, located at the top left side of this answer.

Thank you for your kind cooperation. I believe it is a good practice to follow the rules in an online forum. Thanks!